# Unable to get formFields from callable ChoiceBlock in StreamField

Tags: django-forms, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-apiv2

Unable to get formFields from callable ChoiceBlock in StreamField

I was using a ChooserBlock to get Forms in a dropdown list in a StreamField on my page but now I am upgrading my wagtail version from 3.0 to 4.0.4 in which I refered that ChooserBlock is depreacted and an alternative to use ChoiceBlock was provided. While using this ChoiceBlock which gets **callable** **choices**, I am able to choose my form from the dropdown but it is not getting saved in database   and as a result the fields are not exposed in my API.
Adding code below for reference -
Old (on version 3.0 --> working)

In **StreamField** ->

```
StreamField([("CMS_form", WagtailFormBlock())\],
max_num=1,
blank=True,
use_j`your text`son_field=True)
```

In **wagtailstreamforms** ->

```
class WagtailFormBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
form = FormChooserBlock(required=False)
form_action = blocks.CharBlock(
 required=False,
help_text=_(The form post action. "" or "." for the current page or a url'))
form_reference = InfoBlock(
required=False,
help_text=\_("This form will be given a unique reference once saved "), )
```

class FormChooserBlock(blocks.ChooserBlock):
target_model = Form.objects.all()

```
def value_for_form(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, self.target_model):
        return value.pk
    return value

def value_from_form(self, value):
    if value == "":
        return None
    return super().value_from_form(value)

def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return value
    else:
        try:
            return self.target_model.objects.get(pk=value)
        except self.target_model.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**#Post Upgrade to 4.0.4**

StreamField remains same

In **wagtailstreamforms** ->
class WagtailFormBlock(blocks.StructBlock):

### This form returns empty

```
form = blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=getFormblockChoices, required=False)
form_action = blocks.CharBlock(
    required=False,
    help_text=_(
        'The form post action. "" or "." for the current page or a url'))
form_reference = InfoBlock(
    required=False,
    help_text=_("This form will be given a unique reference once saved "), )

def getFormblockChoices():
return \[(form.id, form.title) for form in Form.objects.all()\]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please let me know

Comment: The code snippets here are unreadable due to the formatting, sorry - you need to either indent the whole section, or wrap it in triple backtick characters (```). I tried editing it myself, but it seems that you've introduced additional errors with stray backslashes and missing quotes.

Comment: I have plenty of ChoiceBlocks that use callables so it is definitely possible. Please share the code for `getFormblockChoices` so we can see if there is something there that looks odd.